# Reducing the dimension of an embedding

Tags: machine-learning, pca, optimization, least-squares, dimensionality-reduction

Let $O \in \mathbb R^{p\times m}$ be a data matrix of observations.

Suppose we are given a model $\mu : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ which is able to approximately fit the observations. Fix $l<n$. We wish to find a sub-model $\varepsilon:\mathbb R^l \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ which will come close to minimizing the following expression:

\begin{equation} \sum_{i=1}^p \left[\min_{y \in \mathbb R^l} \Vert \mu(\varepsilon(y)) - O_i\Vert ^2\right]\end{equation}

Are there standard approaches (algorithms) to solve this problem? What if $\varepsilon$ is restricted to being linear?

Comment: This might be PCA if $\mu$ were linear